# How to run a gitlab-ci.yml job only on a tagged branch?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

How do I run a .gitlab-ci.yml job only on a tagged Master branch?

```
job:
  script:
  - echo "Do something"
  only:
  - master
  - tags
```

The above code will run if either condition exists: a Master branch or a tagged commit.

My goal is to have this run for a production deploy, but it would require that it be on the Master branch and that it be tagged (with a version). Otherwise, I'll have another job that will push to staging if its missing a tag.

Comment: How about running it for tags and checking if tag belongs to master branch in a script?

Comment: I thought it should also work with Variables and tried it with `rules: - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG != null' && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"` and also with `only: refs: - test  variables: - $CI_COMMIT_TAG != null`, but without success...

Comment: @Wolfson The problem with that is that if the pipeline is triggered by a tag, `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is not defined, and viceversa with a commit trigger and `CI_COMMIT_TAG`

Answer (score 42):

This behavior will be introduced in version [12](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/milestones/18).

[Open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27818) was recently update:

> Jason Lenny @jlenny changed title from {-Update .gitlab-ci.yml to
> support conjunction logic for build conditions-} to Conjunction logic
> for build conditions MVC · 2 days ago
>
> Jason Lenny @jlenny changed milestone to 12.0 · 2 days ago

(fingers crossed)

A solution is to use the `except` keyword to exclude all the branches, in conjunction with `only` to run on tags, in this way you run your pipeline only on tag in master branch:

```
  only:
    - tags
  except:
    - branches
```

I'm using version `11.3.4`

Comment: The issue seems to have been migrated to [another issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/60085) - and it missed  12.0, but development of feature is ongoing so it could be available in 12.1.

Comment: How does this run only on tags on master branch? Can't we tag any branch?

Comment: The example will also run on other branches then protected branches.

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser this job runs only when both the conditions are satisfied: you can tag even other branches, but it will be skipped.

Comment: Is the except part really needed? doesn't only tags already exclude everything but tags, which excludes branches as well?

Comment: @Daniel: `branches` means all the branches except the master. The example above allows to run pipelines only when you create a tag on the master branch.

Comment: @SergioTomasello To be precise, "branches" means all brances other than the _default branch_, which can be named master, main, or muppet.

Comment: For a solution that does really only runs for tags that are on selected branches see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756669

Answer (score 27):

Thanks to others like *Matt Alioto* who posted about the [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27818) (which is labeled `Product Vision 2019` so hopefully they knock it out this year).

Specific to *Carlson Cole*'s question, this would work:

```
job_for_master_no_tags:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo "Release to Staging"
  only:
  - master

job_for_master_tags_only:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo "Release to Production"
  only:
  - tags
  except:
  - /^(?!master).+@/    # Ruby RegEx for anything not starting with 'master'
```

- To see how this RegEx works check out https://rubular.com/r/1en2eblDzRP5Ha
- I tested this on GitLab version [11.7.0](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/tags/v11.7.0-ee) and it works

  - Note: If you try to use `- /^(?!master).+/` (without the `@`) it doesn't work - learned that the hard way

Comment: Since 11.9.4 "dangerous" regex, like negative lookaheads (?!), are no longer working. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#supported-onlyexcept-regexp-syntax You can enable them manually though.

Comment: Thanks for heads up @SebastianSebald

Comment: I use the version of 11.2. In my test , it should be end with $. The final resutl is `/^(?!master).+$/`.

Comment: So far I tested it the `job_for_master_tags_only` will also run on other tagged branches

Comment: @kound what version of GitLab were you using?

Comment: 13.7.4 @EricD.Johnson

Answer (score 10):

I made it work with this working code snippet, all others were not working for me

```
only:
 - tags  # please mention the "s" compared to Sergio Tomasello's solution
except:
 - branches
```

I use 11.4.3

Comment: Only tags... this solution doesn't check if the tag is only set on a specified branch.

Comment: @Milkmannetje This was not the question

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I wanted to trigger a deploy to our staging-environment on a **push or merge**, and only when **applying a tag** deploy it our production-environment.

We need 2 variables for this: `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` and `$CI_COMMIT_TAG`. With these variables we could deduct if the pipeline was triggered by a commit or a tag. Unfortunately the first variable is only set when committing on a branch, while the second variable only is set on applying a Tag. So this was no solution...

So I went for the next-best setup by only do a production-release when a tag is set by specified conventions and by a manual trigger.
This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```yaml
stages:
  - deploy:staging
  - deploy:prod

deploy-to-staging:
  stage: deploy:staging
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'master'
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to Staging..."

deploy-to-production:
  stage: deploy:prod
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v(?:\d+.){2}(?:\d+)$/
      when: manual
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to Production..."
```

If you really want to automate this, you have to do a little scripting to find out if the applied tag actually belongs to a commit that is on the master-branch. Check this comment on the GitLab issuetracker for more information: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/31305#note_28580169

Answer (score 7):

Years later, still trying to launch a job on tags on master branch...

The issue at Gitlab has been closed : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/27818

It's not possible to spot a tag on master branch as Git does not work this way. Branches and tags are separate references, each pointing to a commit. So, a tag has no relation with a branch.

My solution is to check the tag name to detect that it represents a PRODUCTION release :

```yaml
deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy-manual
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v\d+.\d+.\d+-?.*$/
  when: manual
```

The regexp matches semver tag names like :

- v1.2.0
- v2.0.0-beta.1
- ...

Comment: This should combine greatly with [protected tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_tags.html).

Answer (score 5):

This behavior is not yet supported by gitlab-ci, although there is an [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/27818) to add it.

In the meantime I've also heard anecdotal reports that

```
only:
  - master
only:
  - tags
```

will get the job done (as well as anecdotal reports that it won't).

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't seem to seem to make any difference. Thanks for the note on the open issue.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is hacking something together with regular expressions like the users [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/issues/639) are experimenting with.

Comment: I just tried the proposed solution and it is indeed working!

Comment: @MattAlioto too bad that link doesn't exist anymore, always try to include a brief example in case the original source goes away ;)

Comment: @JonasD. This seems to be the link you're looking for: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27818

Comment: Per https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27818#note_38463332 second only just overrides the first.

Answer (score 5):

Docs actually say that `only` and `except` are not being developed and that users should use `rules` instead.
Here is an example which will only run on a tag.

```
deploy-to-prod:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  environment:
    name: production
  variables:
    API_ENVIRONMENT: prod
  when: manual
```

Comment: You left out the interesting part of "only on certain / main branch". I didn't find any predefined variable that would tell me which branch(es) this tag is on (i.e. which branch(es) point(s) to the same commit as `$CI_COMMIT_TAG`).

Answer (score 2):

I needed to enable the pipeline only if there is a tag on the HEAD of master and found the following solution:
the condition only checks that the last commit was on a tag.
in the script I compare the tag's commit hash and master HEAD's commit hash and fails the step if they are not equal

```
rules:
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG != null
  when: always
...
script:
# verifying that the tag that triggered the pipeline is done on the head of master
- latest_commit=$(git rev-parse master)
- echo "CI_COMMIT_SHA - $CI_COMMIT_SHA"
- echo "latest_commit - $latest_commit"
- if [ $latest_commit != $CI_COMMIT_SHA ]; then echo "tagging and deploying a version is allowed only on the HEAD of master"; exit 1; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no proper build in solution in gitlab so far for this problem. To keep track of the development of a proper solution and to keep a working workaround updated I created: [Gitlab CI: Run Pipeline job only for tagged commits that exist on protected branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756669/)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue, this is how I tried to solve it

```
my_job:
  stage: build
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
  image: docker:latest
  script:
    - ...
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'master' && $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null
  cache: {}
```

this job runs only when there is a commit on the master branch (excluding any other commit on personal/feature branch). In the very same way I trigger builds on tags:

```
  script:
    - ...
    
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'master' && $CI_COMMIT_TAG != null
```

Comment: CI_COMMIT_BRANCH is not available in merge request pipelines or tag pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

I have found workaround for this.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
build-image-prod:
  stage: image
  only:
    refs:
      - tags
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v.*$/
  script:
      - ./scripts/not-on-main $CI_COMMIT_TAG && exit 0
      - echo "Image building..."
```

scripts/not-on-main:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Missing argument with commit ref."
    exit 0
fi
git fetch origin main
if git branch -r --contains "$1" | grep -q main; then
    echo "Ref $1 is on main branch."
    exit 1
else
    echo "Ref $1 is not on main branch - exiting."
    exit 0
fi
```

The job runs for each tag in repository if name of tag starts with "v". The helper script fetches main and checks if tag is on it. If the tag is not on main branch then the job exits without building.

Answer (score 0):

I handle running pipelines with **specific tags** and also **just the main branch** with the script below:

> **Notice**: you should add the main branch to the list of Protected Branches in GitLab:
>
> **Go to your repository -> Settings -> Repository -> Protected branches --> add here**

And then replace the rules below in your **gitlab-ci** file:

```
rules:
    - if: ( $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^rest_[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/ ) && ( $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "true" )
```

> **CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED** true if the job is running for a protected reference, false otherwise.
>
> **Remember:** **CI_COMMIT_BRANCH** is not available in merge request
> pipelines or tag pipelines.