# GITLAB CI pipeline, run job only with git tag

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

need help from GitLab gurus. I have a following pipeline below.
I expect "sync_s3:prod" job will run only when i will push new git tag. But gitlab trigger both
jobs. Why its behaving like this ? I create $git_commit_tag rule only for one job. Any ideas?

```
stages:
  - sync:nonprod
  - sync:prod

.sync_s3:
  image:
    name: image
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - aws configure set region eu-west-1
    - aws s3 sync ${FOLDER_ENV} s3://img-${AWS_ENV} --delete

sync_s3:prod:
  stage: sync:prod
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      changes:
        - prod/*
  extends: .sync_s3
  variables:
    AWS_ENV: prod
    FOLDER_ENV: prod/
  tags:
    - gaming_prod

sync_s3:nonprod:
  stage: sync:nonprod
  rules:
    - changes:
        - pp2/*
  extends: .sync_s3
  variables:
    AWS_ENV: nonprod
    FOLDER_ENV: pp2/
  tags:
    - gaming_nonprod
```

Comment: Well, I missunderstood your question. Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796018/how-to-run-a-gitlab-ci-yml-job-only-on-a-tagged-branch

Comment: `But gitlab trigger both jobs` When? On tag pipeline or on commit pipeline?

Comment: @KamilCuk 
When i do "git push origin newtag" it trigger both jobs. But as you see i wrote this rule only for one job.

Comment: So you pushed a tag? You stated that `I expect "sync_s3:prod" job will run only when i will push new git tag`, which is true, your job was run on a tag, seems like your requirement is satisfied. So you want to __not__ run the _other_ job on tag?

Comment: Yes, exactly i dont want to run other job on tag. 
What i want to perform fully: 
- Run non-prod job only when i change files inside "pp2" folder. 
- Run prod job only when there is new git tag.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you do not want to have the `sync_s3:nonprod` job run if the `sync_s3:prod` is run. (?)

To achieve this, on the `sync_s3:nonprod` job you should be able to copy the same rule from `sync_s3:prod` together with `when: never`:

```yaml
stages:
  - sync:nonprod
  - sync:prod

.sync_s3:
  image:
    name: image
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - aws configure set region eu-west-1
    - aws s3 sync ${FOLDER_ENV} s3://img-${AWS_ENV} --delete

sync_s3:prod:
  stage: sync:prod
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      changes:
        - prod/*
  extends: .sync_s3
  variables:
    AWS_ENV: prod
    FOLDER_ENV: prod/
  tags:
    - gaming_prod

sync_s3:nonprod:
  stage: sync:nonprod
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      changes:
        - prod/*
      when: never
    - changes:
        - pp2/*
  extends: .sync_s3
  variables:
    AWS_ENV: nonprod
    FOLDER_ENV: pp2/
  tags:
    - gaming_nonprod
```

Comment: What i want to perform fully: - Run non-prod job only when i change files inside "pp2" folder. - Run prod job only when there is new git tag.

Answer (score 1):

As @slauth already mentions in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70112589/10046524) the rules need to be adjusted per step of the pipeline. I only post this as an answer as an addition to the original answer above.
In order to prevent pipeline steps from running when a git-tag is present you need to explicitly set the rule for the corresponding job.

```yaml
stages:
  - sync:nonprod
  - sync:prod

.sync_s3:
  image:
    name: image
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - aws configure set region eu-west-1
    - aws s3 sync ${FOLDER_ENV} s3://img-${AWS_ENV} --delete

sync_s3:prod:
  stage: sync:prod
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      changes:
        - prod/*
  extends: .sync_s3
  variables:
    AWS_ENV: prod
    FOLDER_ENV: prod/
  tags:
    - gaming_prod

sync_s3:nonprod:
  stage: sync:nonprod
  rules:
    - changes:
        - pp2/*
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never
  extends: .sync_s3
  variables:
    AWS_ENV: nonprod
    FOLDER_ENV: pp2/
  tags:
    - gaming_nonprod
```

For further clarification:

The following `rule` will evaluate similar to a logic AND, so this will evaluate to `true` if there is a `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` AND there are changes in `prod/*`. So only when both conditions are met this will be added to the pipeline.

```yaml
rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      changes:
        - prod/*
```